Variable has incomplete type 'Foods' - Why?
I am learning OOP in C++, and I am writing the most basic class. I am having a problem with declaring an object for the class. I getting the error posted in the title. I know my class works because I put the class in "main.cpp", and I could declare an object no problem. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?
My code
Food.h
#ifndef PORJECT2_FOOD_H
#define PORJECT2_FOOD_H

const char* RecommendFood(char firstLetter);
class Foods;

#endif //PORJECT2_FOOD_H


Food.cpp
#include "Food.h"
#include <String>
using namespace std;

class Foods{
public:
    string name;
    int qty;

    const string &getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const string &name) {
        Foods::name = name;
    }

    int getQty() const {
        return qty;
    }

    void setQty(int qty) {
        Foods::qty = qty;
    }
};

main.cpp
    Foods obj;
    string food1 = "Fruit", food2 = "Veggies", Food1, Food2;
    int qty1 = 15, qty2 = 165, QTY1, QTY2;

    obj.setName(food1);
    obj.setQty(qty1);
    Food1 = obj.getName();
    QTY1 = obj.getQty();
    cout << "Food: " << Food1 << " Qty: " << QTY1 << "\n";

    obj.setName(food2);
    obj.setQty(qty2);
    Food2 = obj.getName();
    QTY2 = obj.getQty();
    cout << "Food: " << Food2 << " Qty: " << QTY2 << "\n";

    return 0;
}


The class definition needs to be visible to the compiler where you use it. You need to move the definition to the header file instead of the cpp file. class Foods; is just a forward declaration.

Side note you probably don't want to do this const char* RecommendFood(char firstLetter);.  And return either a std::string or a const std::string& too

What do you have in Food.h? I ask because the Food.cpp looks like it should have been named Food.h. If you plan on having a Food.cpp it should not contain class Foods {}; Instead you would have Foods member functions defined in the cpp file.

You need to declare the structure of Food in the header (class Food { ... }) and then define it in the source file (int Food::getQty() const { ... } etc) (roughly speaking).

Your Food.h only tells its user that a class Foods exists, but provides no information about it so it can't be used for pretty much anything except for a few minor things. This is called a forward declaration.
Now, the way your class is written in Food.cpp has all the functions written inside the class declaration anyway -- so you can just copy the entire thing into the Food.h file and ditch the Food.cpp entirely.
The alternative is to make the class declaration in Food.h only have function declarations like
const std::string &getName() const;

and move the actual implementation to the Food.cpp file like so:
const std::string & Foods::getName() const
{
   return name;
}

But, given the simplicty of the functions, having them in the header is better since the optimizer will completely throw away that getName function and have the caller access the name member variable directly. It can't do such optimizations if the function isn't in the header.
Note that you can mix and match these styles as needed -- like putting simple accessors into the header, and complicated stuff into the .cpp file.
Also, things like Foods::name aren't going to work. You'd either make this this->name, or just give the name parameter a slightly different name such as name_, so it doesn't shadow the member variable.

Name shadowing is bad, definitely don't do that.

how about adding a link to this or this to the answer for further reading (rather than dupe hammering ;)
